# Error: insufficient funds for gas * price + value

Tags: ethereum, go-ethereum, remix

I am going through the [first tutorial in the Ethereum website](https://ethereum.org/greeter).

I've compiled the contract code using Remix and have created the following script. I have removed the binary strings for brevity:

```
var _greeting = 'Hello World!';
var browser_untitled_sol_greeterContract = web3.eth.contract([{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"kill","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"greet","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"name":"_greeting","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"}]);
var browser_untitled_sol_greeter = browser_untitled_sol_greeterContract.new(
 _greeting,
 {
   from: web3.eth.accounts[0], 
   data: 'BINARY_STRING', 
   gas: '4700000'
 }, function (e, contract){
   console.log(e, contract);
   if (typeof contract.address !== 'undefined') {
     console.log('Contract mined! address: ' + contract.address + ' transactionHash: ' + contract.transactionHash);
   }
})

var browser_untitled_sol_mortalContract = web3.eth.contract([{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"kill","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"}]);
var browser_untitled_sol_mortal = browser_untitled_sol_mortalContract.new(
   {
     from: web3.eth.accounts[0], 
     data: 'BINARY_STRING', 
     gas: '4700000'
   }, function (e, contract){
     console.log(e, contract);
     if (typeof contract.address !== 'undefined') {
       console.log('Contract mined! address: ' + contract.address + ' transactionHash: ' + contract.transactionHash);
   }
})
```

When loading this script I get:

`Error: insufficient funds for gas * price + value`.

When calling `eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[0])` I get: `399577000000000`

I can't figure out how much eth I should have in my balance in order to run this script or if I need to convert eth to gas.

Answer (score 2):

You don't "convert" ether to gas. You use ether to pay for gas used.

In any case, the error message you're getting seems correct. Your balance is pretty low. `eth.getBalance()` returns balance in Wei. Your balance is only ~0.0004 ether, which is pretty low (you can convert to ether using https://etherconverter.online/ or convert in code with `web3.fromWei(val, 'ether')`).

The amount of ether you need varies depending on the operations executed in the contract, and how much you're willing to pay for the gas used (you can override the default `gasPrice` in the transaction object). Try mining or transferring more ether into your account.

Comment: It is 1 USD. How can it cost so much to create a contract?

Comment: Not sure how you're coming up with that. .0004 ether < 0.15 USD. The cost will depend on how much logic you have in your contract code and how fast you want it mined.

Answer (score 0):

which kind of network, *testrpc* or *private network* ? if you send transaction on the private network which initialized with `geth init genesis.json` , please do not set `chainId` as `0`